# Read options from file for grunt

Tags: gruntjs

Is there a built-in way to read options from a file, rather than passing arguments on the command line, I would like to be able to read them from a file, like grunt.json or grunt.config.

I realize that it should just be a couple of lines of code but I didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Thanks,
Shane Holder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [grunt.file.readJSON](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.readjson) method to read JSON from a file.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, thanks. But I was hoping for something more built in which would handle the options ordering from argv to the options file like nconf